# Application.ItemSend not called

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I trigger composing a mail from my WPF application.

I register send/close event as following:

```
_mailItem.Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
Inspector inspector = _mailItem.GetInspector;
((InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += MailItem_Close;

// ...

private void MailItem_Close()
{
    Log.Debug("MailItem_Close ...");
}

private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Log.Debug("Application_ItemSend ...");
}
```

I noticed that `MailItem_Close` and `Application_ItemSend` are both not being called when the user clicks on "Send" **without having entered any text in the mail**.

Is there any chance to receive the events even when user didn't input any text in the mail?

**EDIT** I noticed even when user did enter some text the events are not being called every time. So how can I achieve that events are being called always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that both sources of events are alive and declared at the global scope (not swiped by the garbage collector). All of them are fired even if no text is entered into the email.

```
// at the class level you need to define both objects
Outlook.Application app;
Inspector inspector;

// then you can subscribe to the events
app.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
inspector = _mailItem.GetInspector;
((InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += MailItem_Close;

private void MailItem_Close()
{
    Log.Debug("MailItem_Close ...");
}

private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Log.Debug("Application_ItemSend ...");
}
```